# Pip not recognized after update

Tags: python, pip, python-module

[image: Screenshot of all the paths]

Hello, I installed Pandas with pip and then, as my computer said to do, I upgraded Pip. But now, it does not recognize Pip anymore

I've tried so many different ways but it still doesn't work.The last thing I did was install the new Python version.

Thank you !

Comment: I had the same issue, because I had python2 and python3 installed. maybe check that first. that can corrupt your installation.
Also try to run `pip3` it also may be, that it did not install the alias for pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR+Easy solution - `python -m pip install ...`

First of all you can always do `python -m pip install ...` to use pip.

Second try to use `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python\Python38-32\Scripts`

If still doesn't work, show us the full path you inserted and the files manager with that path.